# Getting 405 Error when trying to add contact to my sendgrid using API

Tags: api, sendgrid, http-status-code-405

I am trying to add contacts to my sendgrid using API.

```
const addContactToList = async (email, listId) => {
  try {
    await axios.post(
      `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts`,
      {
        list_ids: [listId],
        contacts: [
          {
            email: email,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${SENDGRID_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )
    console.log('Works')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
```

But I am getting error 405 in return. I have given this specific API key Full Permissions.

[image: Permissions]

Why is the API giving 405 error?

Comment: What is being printed with `error.message`?

Answer (score 0):

To Add or Update a contact the request method must be 'PUT'.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact

[image]